# Where to find pdb/symbol files for old OS (like Windows 2000)

Tags: pdb-files

I am looking for symbol files for Windows server 2000 but does not seem like its any more available to download on microsoft web site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [using their symbol server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311503)? I don't know if that [still?] has symbols for 2000 or not, but it's worth a shot.